# How to execute a TTakePhotoFromCameraAction in other procedure on Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I want to execute a TTakePhotoFromCameraAction in other procedure, but I can't.
I Tested with TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Execute, TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.ExecuteTarget,..., but without success. Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot execute because TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Enabled = False.

Comment: Please check this sample http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces

First: make sure that you able to work with Camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute because TakePhotoFromCameraAction1.Enabled = False.

Please check this sample http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces

First: make sure that you able to work with Camera.